# Как отключить Spring Security в тестах?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, безопасность

Не знаю как отключить Spring Security в тестах в Spring Boot 2 приложении.

получаю ошибку:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'andrew.korzhov.ecommerce.security.JwtTokenProvider' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

это не помогает:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
```

Подмечу, что такой способ работает просто отключит Security в приложении. 
Но в тестах это не помогает.

Еще пробовал в `application.yml` :

```
autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте на классом теста добавить эти аннотации:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, ManagementSecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
```